# WordPress Custom Post Type Category Not Listing

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called track-record (think portfolio). My code is as follows:

```
function track_record_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Track Record', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Track Record Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'track record item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Track Record Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Track Record Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Track Record Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Track Record Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Track Record'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('category'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'track-record' , $args );
}
```

This works fine and I can create a track-record item and assign it to a category. However, when I use WP_Query to list all posts in a category the custom track-record post types that are assigned to the category Track Record do not show up. If I create a post and assign it to the category Track Record in the normal fashion (by going Posts -> Add New instead of Track Record -> Add New) it works fine.

Thoughts? :/

My QP_Query() code:

```
$args = array('cat' => get_cat_id($category));
$category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
        $category_posts->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i></a>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

In the above code for QP_Query() the variable `$category` is the name of the category which WordPress then translates in to the category's ID. This is code is part of a widget as it is much easier for someone to remember the name of a category than it's ID.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out minutes after posting the question here on Stack Overflow.

For anyone that might stumble across this page with the same problem, you have to set `post_type` in the `$args` for WP_Query().

WP_Query() should look like this at the start:

```
$args = array('cat' => get_cat_id($category), 'post_type' => 'track-record');
$category_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```